How to store a nested object/list of nested objects inside of an ObjectBox @Entity without using a relationship?
I'm trying to locally cache a model I'm getting from an API, the model is as follows:
data class Subject(
    val id: Long,
    val meanings: List<Meaning>
    // It has more fields, but they are not relevant
) 

data class Meaning(
    val meaning: String,
    val primary: Boolean,
    val acceptedAnswer: Boolean
)

As you can see, the Meaning model is quite simple and only consists of types supported by Objectbox. The Meanings are entirely unique for each Subject, they are not shared between subjects. More importantly, every time I get updated data from the API and want to overwrite the existing subjects, I want to do so for all the nested objects as well. I need Subject and all the objects nested inside of it to be treated as one thing.
It seems that there is no way to create an equivalent Objectbox @Entity, with a nested object field, or a field that is a list of objects, without using relations. The problem that I am encountering with relations, is that they cannot be simply overwritten as I've described above.
If I have the following entities defined:
@Entity
data class SubjectEntity(
    @Id var id: Long = 0,
    @Index
    @Unique(onConflict = ConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    var apiId: Long = 0,
) {
    lateinit var meanings: ToMany<MeaningEntity>
}

@Entity
data class MeaningEntity(
    @Id var id: Long = 0,
    val meaning: String = "",
    val primary: Boolean = false,
    val acceptedAnswer: Boolean = false
)

...then trying to update the meanings like:
subjectEntity.meanings.apply {
    clear()
    addAll(...)
}

subjectBox.put(subjectEntity)

..keeps all the meanings that were previously there in the box of MeaningEntity, which I don't need. This means I have to manually remove objects from the MeaningEntity box, only the ones I need to be removed in their corresponding subjects, which seems like too much work for something so simple.
Clearly relations aren't what i need. They make no sense for this use-case, and using them feels like I'm creating a second "table" that I need to manage which completely defeats the point of this being a NoSQL database.
Is there a better way to do this?
